# Theano switch in numpy

Tags: numpy

In theano, I have a vector with values around 0 and using switch, I set every value smaller than 0 to 0:

```
T.switch(x < 0, 0, x)
```

How do I the same thing using numpy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```py
import numpy as np
a= np.array([0,1,-12])
a[a<0]= 0
print a
>> [0,1,0]
```

So the key is that `a[a<0]` locate all negative elements.

Answer (score 4):

Answer to question of `numpy` analogue of switch

```
numpy.where(x < 0, 0, x)
```

But specially for this task I prefer using function that was created for this purpose

```
x.clip(0)
```